# I want to filter the length and breath from a given string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-re

I am building a system to calculate the area of the image printed so as to make bills from it.

I have strings like-

"Canvas 36.5 X 48 piece-10"

"wallpaper 3"X27" "(some times we use " to refer to inches)

"Banner 49x87 -10"

"14 Vinyl 38 x 9.7"

"wallpaper 3ftX2Ft PC-1"

and so on like these....

I want to filter floats and intergers from the given data in vba so as to calculate areas of the particular.

like in 1st string i want to fetch 36.5 as length and 48 as breath and 10 as piece and so for the others

so far i am using

```
findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+",myStr)
```

to get all integers and floats and i use first two variables as length and breath but like in "14 Vinyl 38 x 9.7" the len = 38 and breath=9.7 but the algo says 14 and 38 and it is correct on its way, but i want to get the len and breath based on x between them, this will be the correct way of symbolization for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, looks like it should also work as expected:

```py
import re


def l_b_dims_piece(s):
    """Return a tuple of (length, breadth, dimensions, piece)"""
    result = re.findall(r'([\d.]+)\s?(\D{0,2})\s?x\s?([\d.]+)\s?\2?|(\d+)', s, re.IGNORECASE)

    piece = 1
    l = b = 0
    dims = None

    for l_, dims_, b_, piece_ in result:
        if piece_ != '':
            piece = piece_
        else:
            l, b, dims = l_, b_, dims_.replace('"', 'in', 1)

    return l, b, dims, piece
```

Regex playground for testing: [Link](https://regex101.com/r/ZOkJq0/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code.

**Code:**

```py
import re

pictures = ['Canvas 36.5 X 48 piece-10',
    'wallpaper 3"X27',
    'Banner 49x87 -10',
    '14 Vinyl 38 x 9.7',
    'wallpaper 3ftX2Ft PC-1',
    ]

for pic in pictures:
    size = re.search("(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(\D{0,2})[x]\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(\D{0,2})", pic, re.IGNORECASE)
    print(f"'{size.group(0)}' --> {size.groups()}")
```

**Output:**

```py
'36.5 X 48 pi' --> ('36.5', '', '48', 'pi')
'3"X27' --> ('3', '"', '27', '')
'49x87 -' --> ('49', '', '87', '-')
'38 x 9.7' --> ('38', '', '9.7', '')
'3ftX2Ft' --> ('3', 'ft', '2', 'Ft')
```

`size.group(1)` and `size.group(3)` contain the width and height dimensions.

This would also allow you to evaluate the corresponding units (e. g. ft, ", cm?) via `size.group(2)` and `size.group(4)` - in case there are any units. Note, however, that you have to manually check whether a match is a valid unit with this regular expression (see first and third example).

Let me know if you have issues understanding the regular expression.